# Who has the record for the most consecutive races without a DNF in Formula 1?

Tags: formula-1

So far in the 2022 season, Lewis Hamilton is the only driver that has not recorded a DNF or DNS. Who is the driver with the record for the longest streak of race finishes in Formula One?

Comment: Are you asking for the driver who finished the most consecutive races?

Comment: @F1Krazy Yes. I think that my question is a little bit confused and your's is much simpler

Answer (score 1):

It is, in fact, Lewis Hamilton who holds the record. As per [StatsF1](https://www.statsf1.com/en/statistiques/pilote/divers/arrivee-consecutive.aspx), between the 2018 British Grand Prix and the 2020 Bahrain Grand Prix, Hamilton finished **48** Grands Prix in a row. His current streak of consecutive finishes, which began at the 2021 Russian Grand Prix, is only 21 races as of the time of writing.